# How to build llvm/clang for ios with xcode?

Tags: xcode, llvm, cross-compiling

I've extracted llvm/clang/compiler-rt from official sources and created Xcode project:

```
mkdir llvm_34_xcode_build
cd llvm_llvm_34_xcode_build
cmake -G Xcode ../llvm_34
```

I need to cross-compile it to work in iOS simulator (i386 arch) and devices (arm). What cmake arguments to create xcode project or project settings should i set?

Comment: Your terminology is confusing; "build for ios" and "cross-compile it" sounds like you want to actually run clang under iOS, but I *think* you want to build it for x86_64 (OSX) and be able to compile for arm/i386  (iOS)?

Comment: right. cross-compile means i compile it on my mac (x86_64) to run on ios and compile for ios (i386/arm). actually i will use it in my ios app via API (libclang)